# How to pass methods return values to use in mounted

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM1G7.png)Hello, I'm new so I appreciate any feedback.

In my methods, mixed is a nested list. e.g. [['John',34],['Mary',4],['Jack',234]]
I separated into 2 new lists (word and num) and I want to use this list values in mounted. I don't know how to get these list values into mounted section. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ4l7.png)
I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: instead of pictures, provide code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like that.

```
const myWords = this.myFunctionword()
```

or

```
const myNumbers = this.myFunctionnum()
```

Comment: when I console log these, it shows the list is empty

Comment: So what is the **mixed** variable? If it is a variable in Vue Page, you can call it like **this.mixed** but if it is invalid, undefine or null then you can not call it and your list would be empty.

Go **data: () => {}** section, define a variable as **mixed = [(some items here)]** and try again.